# How to look into a external JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I got an URL, for example `https://mycustomjson/<api token>/result?=vars`. I want to import this JSON file into my wordpress site.

While I got the API token to access the data, I do not know how to generate HTML out of it. I know there is a `.getJSON()` [function in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

Is there a way to just display the JSON file to find out, which information are stored in it (and how they are labeled/named? I cannot just open the URL in my browser.

Comment: Do you use any kind of framework? Like AngularJS?

Comment: @Ties no I do not. Do you recommend it?

Comment: If there is a lot of data in JSON or you need to generate rows for the data in HTML I'd suggest using AngularJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, maybe

```
jQuery.getJSON( "https://mycustomjson/<api token>/result?=vars" , function(data) {console.log(data)} );
```

All that does is write the content of `data` to the console. Open your browser's javascript console to see it. (See eg https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this suggestion! I receive an error `source is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`. So there may be an error with my api token. I will try contact the company again and use your method afterwards. Thanks a lot for your help!